# Is there a way to instruct Pylint which libraries should be considered 3rd party?

Tags: python-3.x, pylint

I am running pylint in an environment where certain import libraries are not available and are 3rd party. As a result, pylint generates an error class wrong-import-order C0411 for these imports.

Is there a way to instruct which should be considered 3rd party?

- Pylint 2.1.1
- Python 3.6.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that would be `known-third-party`, which you can set under `[IMPORTS]`:

`# Force import order to recognize a module as part of a third party library.
known-third-party=your modules`